# Saving files and names to database table using for each on request.files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

MVC3 VB.NET Application. I have multiple file upload boxes on a form in my mvc3 application. Request.Files shows 3 files when I put a break point in the below function and look at it.. Problem is other than coding a counter and using a select case I dont see a way to handle saving each file name to the database column it belongs to... Is there away to assign the variable on the fly I guess you could say So that the foreach loop would drop the file in the correct column.. Ie handoutFile1, handoutFile2 , handoutFile3, Etc.... As it stands the below will overwrite the filename in handoutfile1 every time the loop is gone through....I thought about throwing a counter in the loop and just put a select case on it to assign the db column based on the counter number. Seems like a cheap work around though.

```
 For Each File As String In Request.Files

                Dim hpf As HttpPostedFileBase = TryCast(Request.Files(File), HttpPostedFileBase)
                If hpf.ContentLength = 0 Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                Dim savedfileName As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\CourseHandouts\" + hpf.FileName
                hpf.SaveAs(savedfileName)
                _filename = hpf.FileName
                courses.handoutFile1 = _filename

            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know VB.Net but i will try to answer in C# code,

In your action you can define in parameter as

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IList<HttpPostedFileBase> postedFiles)
    {
        foreach (var file in postedFiles)
        {
            //
        }
        return View();
    }
```

and in the view like the following,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"  }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>TestModel</legend>
    @Html.TextBox("postedFiles[0]",null, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.TextBox("postedFiles[1]",null, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.TextBox("postedFiles[2]",null, new { type = "file" })
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: No dice on that one because In the for each loop it needs to save to a different database column each file name..

Answer (score 0):

Your database design seems wrong. Instead of trying to save each individual file in a separate column, you could create another table that will contain all files as rows and which will have a foreign key to the first table to match the record. So you will basically have `courses.handoutFiles` which will be an array instead of having `courses.handoutFile1`, `courses.handoutFile2`, ...

If on the other hand for some reason you need to work with the initial schema and save into separate columns, you don't have much choice other than using ugly code.